# How to show a menu after clicking on the widget icon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using firefox addon builder (Addon kit 1.7) and I wonder to know if it's possible to show a simple menu like the context menu of firefox just after clicking on the widget icon. I need few hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should be hard with the Add-on SDK - a menu needs to be implemented in XUL, this is usually done with classic extensions. You can fake a menu with some HTML-based library however.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Thank you for your valuable comment. I think showing a html based menu in a panel will do the trick. I wonder if it's possible to restyle the panel and remove its border. Something that looks a little bit similar to panel in Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: As far as i know i dont think you can restyle the panels border. But the content within it can definitely be modified with the help of css and some html.

Comment: Not by regular means. One would need to somehow get hold of the XUL node that the `widget` module creates and modify its `style` attribute. This needs to rely on a bunch of assumptions about internals however, it is probably easier to fork the `widget` module instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work using the MenuPopup package by Yaelle Borghini and uploaded a [simple example](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1059945/latest) on the Addon Builder site.

You will have to expand on Yaelle's code to support dynamic modifications of the menu items because it's not fully built in at the moment (though it shouldn't be too hard to add it).

Here's the [discussion](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?p=17129&sid=5aa25f0466f27d8fd2ce0fe6c8b0ff4c) on the Mozilla forums about how to show menus with the Addon SDK that got me started.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only option is to hook a panel to a widget and add a menuitem to the panel with html.